# New replacement code signing certificate for java web start application showing as expired or not yet valid?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jar-signing

I just replaced my code signing certificate as the old one expired.

---

I have imported and signed my java program with the new certificate, validated that it was signed with the new certificate

> [entry was signed on 9/18/19 11:06 AM]

and that the dates are valid

> [certificate is valid from 9/17/19 5:00 PM to 8/28/20 4:59 PM]

, but I am getting the following warning when I launch the java web start program from either my computer or from my website:

> "Application Blocked by Java Security...Reason: Your security settings have blocked an application signed with an expired or not-yet-valid certificate from running."

I contacted Sectigo and they tried replacing certificate and having me download the replacement from IE instead of Firefox, but  the replacement certificate is doing the same thing. :0

*Any help is very appreciated. :) :)*

Comment: Is the old jar cached on your machine i.e. client-side?

Comment: Thank you for responding! Ug. I had cleared all browser caches, and (I think) the computer cache and reset the wifi (would that be enough?) still no change. So I tried clearing the temporary java cache. Result: instead of telling me that the code signing certificate is not valid, it cannot open the application; it cannot find the lib/jsoup folder. It seems to be putting the lib/jsoup file within the dist file now, but still looks for it in the main directory. Everything had worked file before the certificate expired.  (it was timestamped, so I didn't think I would have to deal with all this?!)

Comment: So - ultimately this was the right suggestion.  Clearing the temporary  java cache seems to have repaired the certificate issue.  It did mess up jarsigner somehow ("this application does not work on this computer," and I had to reinstall JAVA - which somehow resulted in jsoup being put into my application's library?  Which caused the application to fail because jsoup was claiming to be unsigned if I moved it to where the application could find it, but once I took that out - all good! Thank you Dave Thompson.